# Unboundlocalerror: local variable ' pulse_start' is referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-2.7, sensors

It stated that `unboundlocalerror: local variable 'pulse_start' referenced before assignment`. I run it previously and so sudden error happen.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO, time
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
def ultrasonicfunction(DistanceOfWaterLevelFromSensor):
    GPIO.cleanup()
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

    TRIG = 23
    ECHO = 18

    GPIO.setup(TRIG, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(ECHO, GPIO.IN)

    GPIO.output(TRIG, False)
    time.sleep(1)

    GPIO.output(TRIG, True)
    time.sleep(0.00001)
    GPIO.output(TRIG, False)

    while GPIO.input(ECHO) == 0:
        pulse_start = time.time()

    while GPIO.input(ECHO) == 1:
        pulse_end = time.time()

    pulse_duration = pulse_end - pulse_start

    distance = pulse_duration * 17000
    if distance > 44:
        DistanceOfWaterLevelFromSensor = "0"
        print
        'Please place the ultrasonic sensor near the water tank'
    # Watertank height = 44cm,
    else:
        DistanceOfWaterLevelFromSensor = 44 - distance
        DistanceOfWaterLevelFromSensor = "%.2f" % round(DistanceOfWaterLevelFromSensor, 2)

    return DistanceOfWaterLevelFromSensor
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen if `GPIO.input(ECHO)` never equals 0 or 1?

Answer (score 0):

**edit:**

you need to declare **pulse_start** and **pulse_end** first just in case you don't go in the loop

```
   pulse_start = 0 
   pulse_end   = 0
   while GPIO.input(ECHO) == 0:
        pulse_start = time.time() loop

    while GPIO.input(ECHO) == 1:
        pulse_end = time.time()
```

Comment: `pulse_start` _will_ be accessible after the end of the loop.

Comment: ...But won't be assigned if you never enter the loop (i.e. if `GPIO.input(ECHO)` does not equal 0), as stated in the error message...

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your variables before the `while` loop, like so:

```
pulse_start = 0
pulse_end = 0

while GPIO.input(ECHO) == 0:
    pulse_start = time.time()

while GPIO.input(ECHO) == 1:
    pulse_end = time.time()
```